# Kotlin edittxt.onKeyListener with emulator keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to reset a button to become clickable once a key on the keyboard is pressed. It works with the hardware keyboard but not with the emulator keyboard. How would one implement this?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.log_in_button)
            val email = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email_field)

            button.isClickable = false
            button.alpha = .5f

            email.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener {
                override fun onKey(v: View, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {

                    if(event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                        button.isClickable = true
                        button.alpha = 1f
                        return true
                    }

                    return false
                }
            })
}
```

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this with the software keyboard within the emulator.

Comment: Is your code working ? if yes, then you probably want a review, and your question may suite better to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If no, then what is not working ? is it crashing ? what is the error ? in which line ? Is it working but not the way you want ? What is actual behaviour ? the expected one ?  Currently your question is unclear...

Comment: When you say hardware keyboard im I thought to assume that you mean you ran on your physical device? And the emulator keyboard is the built in on in android studio? If so I've heard of this before. If it works on the physical phone that means it's right and it's a big in the emulator.